# ASP.net using OWIN for Azure Active Directory Federation Services Single Sign On

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, adfs

I am working on a project, based on this solution:  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation

Currently, the way I have the user authenticate is by default. When the page loads, I call my login script:

```
Public Sub SignIn()
        If (Not Request.IsAuthenticated) Then
            Try
                Dim newAuth As AuthenticationProperties = New AuthenticationProperties()
                newAuth.RedirectUri = "/"

                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(newAuth, WsFederationAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

        End If
    End Sub
```

**EDIT**
To add more context, here is my code for APP_START/Startup.Auth.vb:

```
Partial Public Class Startup

        Private realm As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:RPIdentifier")
        Private aadInstance As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:AADInstance")
        Private tenant As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:Tenant")
        Private metadata As String = String.Format("{0}/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml", aadInstance)
        Private authority As String = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant)   


        Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
            Try
                app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
                app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())
                Dim authOption As WsFederationAuthenticationOptions = New WsFederationAuthenticationOptions()

                app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(New WsFederationAuthenticationOptions() With {
                     .Wtrealm = realm,
                     .MetadataAddress = metadata,                        
                     .Notifications = New WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications() With {
                     .AuthenticationFailed = Function(context)
                                                 context.HandleResponse()
                                                 context.Response.Redirect("Home/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message)
                                                 Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                             End Function
                                        }
                        })
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw ex
            End Try


        End Sub


    End Class
```

What I want to avoid, though, is if someone from outside our network views the site, I don't want them to be redirected to the Azure Single Sign On login page.  I just want them to proceed to the website, where my code will handle what they can see and do.  I will, eventually, add a login button that will take them to the login page, in the event they are just off site.  But, for now, how do I skip the login page?

Second, I want to handle the possibility that Azure ADFS is down.  In this case, I just want the user to be redirected to the website, as un-authenticated users.  I test this by disconnecting from the Internets and running my app.  I've tried using Try blocks, but  I still get these errors:

> The remote name could not be resolved: 'adfs.myCompany.com'
>
> IOException: Unable to get document from:
>   https://adfs.myCompany.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
>
> [InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain
>   configuration from:
>   'https://adfs.myCompany.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml'.]

Are these settings in Azure I should be making or in my code?  Any help, with either of these issues, would be great.  I needed, I can also add my Start.Auth.vb code, as well.

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to solve? What will be the benefit? How you can possibly check if someone is inside your network? Based on IP address range?

Comment: @cloudikka The scenario I am trying to address is if someone views my webpage and is not auto Single Signed On.   Usually, if the user is not on the network, they will be brought to a generic sign in page.  I do not want that to happen.  I want them to proceed to my website, where I will limit what they can see.  I will then provide a link where they can go an sign in, if they wish.  Not everyone who view my site will be a member of our network, so therefor should not be required to be redirected.  Also, there are times when our Azure ADFS is not reachable, so I want to handle that error too

Comment: Auto-redirect to ADFS is happening whenever user is not authorize. So, I assume you have authorize attribute defined in global filters as you are saying users are redirected automatically to authentication provider. Correct?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, using the samples Microsoft provides will enforce auto-sign on. 
That being said, there are two options:

1. Choose a different [authentication scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios)
2. Use a an Azure application with an [oAuth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) to sign in when a user clicks the login in link, then read the user's profile and determine their authorization rights.

If I misunderstood, please let me know. Hope this helps!

Comment: It can be done. You can intercept the authentication. The problem is how to check the network.

Comment: @emmanuel Ferran thank you for your response.  Normally, I would take what you provided and try to figure out what you are suggesting, but this is for a bounty.  Per the bounty, I am asking for examples of how to do this work.